# Laravel - Column not found: 'full_name'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my [laravel-8](/questions/tagged/laravel-8), I have a model whereby I tried to concatenate:

```
protected $appends = 'full_name';

public function getFullNameIdAttribute()
{
    return ucfirst($this->last_name) . ', ' . ucfirst($this->first_name). ' ' . ucfirst($this->other_name);
}
```

I want to concatenate the employee's `name` from the model.

Controller:

```
public function employeeParameters()
{
    try {
        $employees = Employee::select('full_name', 'id')->get();
        return $this->success('Vehicle Detail.', [
            'employees' => $employees,
        ]);
    } catch(\Throwable $e) {
        Log::error($e);

        return $this->error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name'

And points to this line:

```
$employees = Employee::select('full_name', 'id')->get();
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use `full_name` as a Column in a `select`, since it isn't a column, but a property. Your code should work with `$employees = Employee::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'other_name', 'id')->get();`, since you included `protected $appends = 'full_name';` (that might need to be an array though, like `protected $appends = ['full_name'];`)

Comment: @TimLewis - How do I now achieve this. I want to contatenate first_name, last_name and other_nme from the laravel backend

Comment: Did you read my comment? **Your code should work if you change it to: `$employees = Employee::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'other_name', 'id')->get();`**. Did you try that?

Comment: Also note that your attribute is named `getFullNameIdAttribute`, which would translate to `full_name_id`, not `full_name`

Comment: @TimLewis - When I used getFullNameIdAttribute, I still got the same error

Comment: Please read up on how accessors work: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators. When you define `getFullNameAttribute()`, you can access that via `$employee->full_name`. It doesn't create a column on your database table, so you can't use `->select('full_name')`, but if you did `$employee = Employee::select('first_name', 'last_name', 'other_name', 'id')->first()`, then you'd be able to access it like `$employee->full_name`. Since you're using `->get()`, you'd have to loop: `foreach ($employees as $employee){ ... }`, then in that loop, `$employee->full_name`. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score -3):

you can achieve this via aliasing like this

```
Employee::select(\DB::raw("CONCAT(`first_name`,' ',`last_name`) AS `full_name`"))->get();
```